# Post Doc position in USA after j-1 visa?

Tags: phd, united-states, career-path, visa

I don't know if this is the right section.

I am a Ph.D. student in Italy in my second year (next year, It will be the last one). I have been accepted for a research internship at Cornell from June to January. Right now, I am doing the J-1 visa "professor and research scholar".

This type of visa is subject to 2-Year Repeat Participation Bar.

If I want to do a PostDoc in the US, I will have to wait a year to be able to do a j-1 visa. I'm a little worried that this could be a big limitation for my career.

At the same time, I am thinking that I am rushing out too much and It would be a nonsense to reduce the research internship in order to have a J-1 visa for "short term scholar" (max 6 months).

Have you any advice?

Comment: Are you simply asking whether or not you should cut your stay short (6 months instead of 8), so that you can have a chance at securing a postdoc in the U.S. after you graduate? Surely the answer to that depends entirely on how much you want to do a postdoc in the U.S.! If it were me and if I were serious about trying to find a postdoc in the U.S. after I graduate, it would be a no-brainer to do 6 months instead 8 if possible. (But keep in mind the home residency thing mentioned in the answer of J.Galt.)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, there are two things to watch out for: the two-year home residency requirement, and the repeat participation bar.

The two-year home residency requirement depends on your type of funding, but can be waived if both the U.S. and your home country agree. To my knowledge, there are some countries which always agree (e.g., Sweden, Germany) and some countries who almost never do (e.g., India, China). From what I have heard, Italy is in a bit of a danger zone - a friend of mine did get a waiver agreement from the U.S.'s side, but not from Italy. I heard conflicting things about this, though.

As for the two-year repeat participation bar, there is no waiver for that, as far as I know. This doesn't mean that you can't work in the U.S., just that you cannot do so under a J-1 visa immediately again (see, e.g., the description [here](https://isss.temple.edu/faculty-staff-and-researchers/j-1-research-scholars-professor/prospective-j-1-exchange-visitors/research-scholar-vs-short-term-scholar)). For instance, you could try to get an [O-1 visa status](https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/temporary-workers/o-1-visa-individuals-with-extraordinary-ability-or-achievement), but that is a quite involved process, from what I have heard.

Personally, I would not sweat this decision. If you don't want to limit the length of your stay to get the short-term scholar category, I would say just go for it. You can always bridge the period until you are eligible again with postdoc positions in other countries. And if you want to return Cornell, you'll likely already have one foot in the door anyways.

In any case, I would recommend contacting the [international services of Cornell](https://international.globallearning.cornell.edu/). They know the ins-and-outs of the relevant immigration rules and could certainly give you more precise advice!

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, you are probably right, I should not swat this decision. I am not 100% sure about doing a post-doc in the USA, and even if I chose so, it would be only one year or less, and I have already been offered a research grant for 1/2 year where I am doing Ph.D., so I would not be a problem.